# Suboptimal Early Stopping prevents overfitting in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, cross-validation, xgboost

I have been using the early stopping feature of xgboost for variety of problem statements, mostly classification. But I have the following observation when working on couple of datasets of different domains

- At point of minimum evaluation error, but where the difference between train and test (used for evaluation to stop training rounds) errors is relatively high, the model seems to behave as if there has been over-fitting.
- In such situations when I consider stopping training rounds at point at which both train and test (evaluation data during training) errors are reasonably similar (though evaluation error is not at minimum), the models perform better and as per the error terms estimation.

Therefore the question is: should the number of training rounds be stopped much earlier than at the optimal point (where there is a very high divergence error between train and test (eval), though validation error is lower)?

Please assume that every care has been taken to correctly split the datasets for train, test, validation, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: The error gap between training and validation doesn't relate to overfit at all.. The gap between them tells you nothing about the number of iterations your model should train.

Comment: Thanks Eran Moshe. Let me know, based on your experience, if there is any OTHER interpretation you can derive from this error gap being high or low..

Comment: Directly no. If the gap is insane, the two datasets are totally different or your model doesn't generalized on the problem at all. Another approach to understand what is going on is drawing a Learning Curve. This is where I've learnt about Learning Curves: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISBGFY-gBug . If you still need more assistant with the learning curves, formalize a different question and we'll solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Early stopping in xgboost works as follows:

- **It looks over the last tuple of your "watchlist" (usually you put the validation/testing set) there**
- **It evaluates this set by your evaluation metric**
- **If this evaluation hasn't changed for `x` times (where `x = early_stopping_rounds`)**
- **The model stops train, and know where was the best iteration (with the best evaluation of your test/validation set)**

Yes, your model will be built with `x` unnecessary iterations (boosters). But assuming you have a trained `xgboost.Booster` in `clf`

```
# Will give you the best iteration
best_iteration = clf.best_ntree_limit

# Will predict only using the boosters untill the best iteration
y_pred = clf.predict(dtest, ntree_limit=best_iteration)
```

Which concludes a **no**, to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you stop early, your parameters would not fit your training data well. On the other hand, if you are overfitting, you would fail the validation set. What you could do (perfect rule of thumb), is stop when at the parameters that your validation error minimum. This is assumed that training error always goes down as epochs of iterations increase but that for validation set goes down and then goes up. 
For project, this should works good enough. While for more advanced application, you would want to search validation techniques like cross validation. But the idea is similar.

Comment: Generally speaking stopping at point of validation error being minimum seems fine, however if at that point there is a wide divergence between train and test(validation error) then models have not performed as estimated, but stopping at a higher validation error point where divergence is reasonable gave performance as projected by error terms.

Comment: That correct. But you should realize that the test data should not be available. That indicates, in practice, you would only divide you data into two set (training and validation). The divergence between validation error and test error should have a lot of reasons like bias in the data splitting or practical noise. But that is all you can do. If you are in a class competition, you would want to use 80% of your data for training and 20% for validation. The correction of your model is evaluated by your professor.

Comment: Also. In practice. The validation error is always not a strict first goes down then goes up curve. You would want to find a point that both training error and validation error are reasonable low. The “reasonable” is really heuristic.